# university loci question

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

My problem is finding the locus of points which satisfy this relationship
$$|z − 1| = \frac{\arg(z − 1)}{2\pi}$$
I'm struggling to deal with both a modulus and an argument

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: try editing your question using MathJax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Arg$(z-1)=\phi$

WLOG $z-1=\dfrac\phi{2\pi}e^{i\phi}$

If $z=x+iy, x-1=\dfrac\phi{2\pi}\cos\phi,y=\dfrac\phi{2\pi}\sin\phi$

What if $\phi=0?$

Else on division $\tan\phi=\dfrac y{x-1},$

$\dfrac{\cos\phi}{x-1}=\dfrac{\sin\phi}y=\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt{y^2+(x-1)^2}}$

$x-1=\dfrac\phi{2\pi}\cos\phi=\dfrac{\pm\phi (x-1)}{2\pi\sqrt{y^2+(x-1)^2}}\implies \sqrt{y^2+(x-1)^2}=\pm\dfrac\phi{2\pi}$

Now by [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) $\phi\le\pi$

Comment: It seems that $ z -1 = \frac {1}{8\sqrt 2} + \frac {i}{8\sqrt 2} $ is a solution for which the argument is not  $2 \pi$.

Comment: @Swapnil, Please pinpoint the mistake.

Comment: Mistake in Second last equation: $\dfrac\phi{2\pi}\cos\phi≠\dfrac{\pm\phi (x-1)}{2\pi} $

Comment: @Swapnil, Thanks for observation, Just could not make out the flaw

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean principal argument: -$-\pi \lt arg(z-1) \leq \pi$

If all you need is the locus and not an idea about the points themselves, then let $z=x+iy$

I assume you know how to find the argument of a complex number.

So that gives: $$ 2\pi (\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2)}) = \arctan (\frac {y}{x-1}) + k \pi $$

Where k is either 0, 1 or -1

From this, since the RHS is less than $\pi$ so at least we know:

$(\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2)} \leq \frac {1}{2} $